# updating python dictionary values

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm adding and updating a python dictionary. Currently it looks pretty ugly and is hard to read, is there a nicer way of doing the same thing?

```
        if not transaction_id in self.transaction_log:
            self.transaction_log[transaction_id] = {
                'gross_total': 0,
                'net_total': 0,
                'qty_total': 0,
                'tax_total': 0
            }
            self.transaction_log[transaction_id]['products'] = {}


        # create a list of dics to be reused in
        # other class methods
        self.transaction_log[transaction_id].update({
            'transaction_id': transaction_id,
            'transaction_time': transaction_datetime,
            'location_id': location_id,
            'till_id': till_id,
            'employee_id': employee_id,

        })

        self.transaction_log[transaction_id]['products'][product_id] = {
            'gross': gross,
            'net': net,
            'tax': tax,
            'qty': qty
        }

        self.transaction_log[transaction_id]['gross_total'] += gross
        self.transaction_log[transaction_id]['net_total'] += net
        self.transaction_log[transaction_id]['qty_total'] += tax
        self.transaction_log[transaction_id]['tax_total'] += qty
```

Comment: Could we have a bit more context for this code? Simply refactoring code that already works is usually handled on http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: two things I would suggest is to make a reference to `self.transaction_log[transaction_id]` at the beginning of the snippet so you can refer to it as a local variable, and you set `self.transaction_log[transaction_id]['products'] = {}` but can just add `'products':{}` in the definition right above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be more appropriate for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) :

```
transaction = self.transaction_log.setdefault(transaction_id, { 'products': {} })

# create a list of dics to be reused in
# other class methods
transaction.update({
    'gross_total': transaction.get('gross_total', 0) + gross,
    'net_total': transaction.get('net_total', 0) + net,
    'qty_total': transaction.get('qty_total', 0) + qty,
    'tax_total': transaction.get('tax_total', 0) + tax,
    'transaction_id': transaction_id,
    'transaction_time': transaction_datetime,
    'location_id': location_id,
    'till_id': till_id,
    'employee_id': employee_id
})
transaction['products'].update({
    product_id: {
        'gross': gross,
        'net': net,
        'tax': tax,
        'qty': qty
    }
})
```

Also, it looks like you reversed `qty` and `tax`

Comment: unfortunately `dict.update` doesn't work recursively, so if `'products'` already exists it will be completely overridden removing any other `product_id` entries that may be there.

Comment: good catch @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen. the answer has been updated.

Comment: I also noticed that - because you are using `transaction.get('gross_total', 0)` there is no need for it to be defined above so you could simplify the first statement to be just `transaction = self.transaction_log.get(transaction_id, {'products':{}})` or better yet use `setdefault` instead of `get` so you don't need to reassign it at the bottom.

Comment: you're a genius @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen. editing it now